# How to transpile into commonjs the import of an ESM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, es6-modules, commonjs

I am building a package which must be in commonjs because the project is going to use it does not support import/export yet.

My package has a dependency on [another package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) `globby` which is ESM only.

I thought to use babel and transpile all my code, expecting `babel` to transpile the `import` into some form of dynamic import which should always work. However, this idea does not work. When the project calls my package, it throws:

```js
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /mydir/project/node_modules/globby/index.js
from /mydir/project/node_modules/mypackage/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in 
/mydir/project/node_modules/mypackage 
to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

I would expect `babel` to transpile my

```
import {globby} from 'globby'
```

into something can be used by commonJS, but it did not happen.

I am using version `7.19` and `babel.config.js` is

```json
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true)
  const presets = [['@babel/preset-env',
    {
      "loose": true,
      "targets": { "node": 16 },
      "modules": 'commonjs'
    }
  ]]
  const ignore = ['./src/tooltip.js']
  const plugins = ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", {
      "allowTopLevelThis": true
    }]]
  return { presets, ignore, plugins }
}
```

Comment: You would have to transpile `globby`, too. If you want to write a CJS module, you should only use CJS modules.

Comment: @jabaa I thought about that, but is this the correct approach?

Comment: Have you read the error message? `Instead change the require of index.js in 
/mydir/project/node_modules/mypackage 
to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.` That's an alternative approach.

Comment: @jabaa yes and I expecting babel to do it which is not happening.  Can babel convert an `import` into a `dynamic import` ?

Comment: I don't think Babel can handle it. I found https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs, but it seems like this plugin can't transform the `globby` import.